# how many times a name is in a message? python 2.x

Tags: python, string, list, count, output

ex of what text.txt looks like

Fri Aug 8

name **fred** @ all hi how are you doing

read by george hannah irene

Fri Aug 8

name **george** @ fred not bad so far and you

read by fred hannah irene

Fri Aug 8

name **hannah** @ fred a little tired

read by fred george irene

Sat Aug 9

name **irene** @ all what do you guys want to do over the weekend

read by fred george hannah

Sat Aug 9

name **fred** @ irene I want to go ice skating

read by george irene

Sat Aug 9

name **irene** @ fred let's go

read by fred george

Sat Aug 9

name **fred** @ ....

etc .... with more messages

So I got this part of my code

input

```
fhand = open('text.txt')

for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith('name ') : continue
    words = line.split()    
    output_name = word[1]
# which will give me just the BOLD names
```

but how do I continue and finish the code so that I can join the out put of these names together? so the print would be in a list

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
['fred', 'george', 'hannah', 'irene', 'fred', 'irene' 'etc..']
```

keeping the duplicated names. append gives me a list without the duplicated name.

How do I get all of the output names in a list? Not sure of how to define a list of output names that I generated.

My end goal is to find all of the names and count up how many times they occur in the text.txt file. I was thinking of making a list of names then counting them up but I'm not sure of how to create that list to count. I don't wan t it to count up the @name just the from name's name in bold. How many times each person posted a message?

DESIRED FINAL OUTPUT

```
fred: 3 # or actual number times of occurrence / count
george: 1 # or actual number times of occurrence / count
hannah: 1 # or actual number times of occurrence / count
irene: 2 # or actual number times of occurrence / count
```

TRIED

print list(output_name) gives me

NOT desired output

```
[ 'f', 'r', 'e', 'd']
```

....

which is not what I want.

Thank you in advance for your help!
pardon my lack of proper jargon, I'm still a beginner programmer in python.

Comment: I'm not sure of how to create a dictionary with all of this...

Comment: I know how to create the dictionary part (I thnk) but not sure of how to get my list of names to count up in the dictionary. How do I generate the list of names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use `list.count`, e.g.:

```
>>> ['fred', 'george', 'hannah', 'irene', 'fred', 'irene'].count('fred')
2
```

Or, build a dictionary when iterating:

```
counter = {}
for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith('name ') : continue
    words = line.split()    
    output_name = word[1]
    try:
        counter[output_name] += 1
    except KeyError:
        counter[output_name] = 1
```

Or, use built-in `Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(['fred', 'george', 'hannah', 'irene', 'fred', 'irene'])
Counter({'fred': 2, 'irene': 2, 'george': 1, 'hannah': 1})
```

And at last, to print from dict:

```
for name, count in counter.items():
    print("{}: {}".format(name, count)
```

Comment: Thank you! The try and except part of the counter worked in my code! building the dictionary is what I needed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use Dictionary to count your item from a list

```
fhand = open('text.txt')
names=[]
for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith('name ') : continue
    words = line.split()    
    output_name = words[1]
    names.append(output_name)
# which will give me just the BOLD names 
L = ['apple','red','apple','red','red','pear']
allcount = {}
[allcount .__setitem__(item,1+allcount.get(item,0)) for item in names]
print(allcount )
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can do it using `regex`:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

results = Counter(re.findall('(\w+) @', data))
for name, value in results.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(name, value))
```

Output:

```
fred: 2
george: 1
hannah: 1
irene: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to create a dictionary and store the names and the number of times they occur.

```
    from collections import defaultdict
    fhand = open('text.txt')

    name_count = defaultdict(int)    
    for line in fhand:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if not line.startswith('name ') : continue
        words = line.split()    
#        output_name = word[1]
        name_count[words[1]] += 1

    print(name_count)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But when I tried print(name_count) I get output: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {}) did I do something wrong? I'm using python 2.x, would this work?

Comment: Yes. This will work in python 2.x. Can you try printing line and words in the loop? Also, there was a small error in my code. I was using 'word' instead of 'words'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the counts to a list:

```
fhand = open('text.txt')
names = [] # an empty list to hold the names
for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith('name ') : continue
    words = line.split()    
    names.append(word[1])
```

Now the `names` list hold the names. To count the frequencies, you can do the following:

```
import collections
freq = collections.Counter(names)
```

Now `freq` will be a Counter object, which is similar to a dictionary, that will contain the number of occurrences of each name. For example, `freq['fred']` will return the number of occurrences of the name 'fred'.

As a side note, I would suggest not to use `continue` whenever possible - it makes the code less clear. Instead of that, use `if ... else`:

```
fhand = open('text.txt')
names = [] # an empty list to hold the names
for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith('name '):
        words = line.split()
        names.append(word[1])
```

This way your code make your intention ("extract names") much clearer.

if you now want to do something (i.e., print) with the frequency results, you can go over the dictionary:

```
for k, v in freq.items():
    print(k, v)
```

(of course you could use `print` to better format the results.)

Comment: Thank you for the if .. else advise!  but when I tried print names output: []
print freq output: Counter() did I do something wrong? I'm using python 2.x, would this work?

Comment: `collections.Counter` exists in Python2 and should work. What exactly did you try? As I said, `collections.Counter()` returns a dictionary - maybe you need to look it up and learn how to work with a dictionary. In short, instead of trying to call `print` on it, run a loop over the dictionary's items and print each one of them.

Comment: Thank you, I will look it up. Another question, is ther anyway to see or check what exactly is inside thte names list? You said "Now the names list hold the names. " but I'm unable to see the list when I try to print (names) output: nothing? I want to know how to create that list.

Comment: If you have specific question, or you've tried some code and it is not working as expected, it would be best if you ask a new question and provide full details (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an how to ask). Also, if I may suggest, you are asking very basic questions so maybe you should look for a good basic tutorial to Python and Python's collections.